# Failed global initialization: FileRenameFailed: Could not rename preexisting log file

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I get this error while trying to launch mongo deamon.

> CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileRenameFailed: Could
> not rename preexisting log file
> "/var/lib/mongodb/log/mongod.log" to
> "/var/lib/mongodb/log/mongod.log.2021-12-02T14-32-24"; run
> with --logappend or manually remove file: Permission denied

config

```
storage:
        dbPath: "/var/lib/mondodb/data"

systemLog:
        destination: file
        path: "/var/lib/mongodb/log/mongod.log"
```

`mongodb` has ownership of `/var/lib/mongodb` and subdirs. Permissions are supposed to be fine.

mondodb dir

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Dec  2 15:42 config
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Dec  2 15:41 data
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Dec  2 15:42 log
```

The service itself won't run either

`> sudo service mongod status`

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-06 17:09:38 GMT; 1s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 24234 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 24234 (code=exited, status=100)

Dec 06 17:09:37 GEL-R90VQK84 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 06 17:09:38 GEL-R90VQK84 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Dec 06 17:09:38 GEL-R90VQK84 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the deamon as root?

Check the ownership of the file

> /var/lib/mongodb/log/mongod.log

Comment: I don't run mongodbd as root. The owner of the whole dir `/var/lib/mongodb/`  is `mongodb`.
If I run as root I don't get any errors in console yet the process terminates anyway, and I see a "Permission denied" line in the log on the same file.

Comment: Can you check who is the owner of the log file?

Comment: over a fresh installation, as I said running the deamon without root permissions doesn't create the log file. If I run the deamon with sudo, `root` is the owner.

Comment: This is the only line I get in the log (running as `root`): `mongod.log: Permission denied`

Comment: If you delete the log file (with root) and try to start again mongodb without sudo?

Comment: I think it is not only a permission issue, I think my mongodb installation is broken, I get the same errors even if I set log and data dirs in `/home/mysuser/mongodb`

Comment: Very extrange! Try to reinstall it.

Comment: just tried. Dumb question: before launching my deamon, should I run `sudo service mongod start` (with no custom config) ?

Comment: No, you must start with fork and if you want specify the log file:

mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log


https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/